# jQuery gets my buttons after pressing arrow buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the below code, pressing C or V should change speed of that ball.
Press V ~10 times and after 5-10 seconds press an arrow button. Where is my mistake?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

function circle(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

function ball() {
  this.speed = 5;
  this.x = width / 2;
  this.y = height / 2;
  this.xSpeed = this.speed;
  this.ySpeed = 0;
  this.size = 5;
};
ball.prototype.move = function() {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;

  if (this.x < 0) {
    this.x = width;
  } else if (this.x > width) {
    this.x = 0;
  }

  if (this.y > height) {
    this.y = 0;
  } else if (this.y < 0) {
    this.y = height;
  }
};
ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  circle(this.x, this.y, this.size, true);
};
ball.prototype.setDirection = function(direction) {
  if (direction === "up") {
    this.xSpeed = 0;
    this.ySpeed = -this.speed;
  } else if (direction === "down") {
    this.xSpeed = 0;
    this.ySpeed = this.speed;
  } else if (direction === "right") {
    this.xSpeed = this.speed;
    this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "left") {
    this.xSpeed = -this.speed;
    this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "stop") {
    this.xSpeed = 0;
    this.ySpeed = 0;
  }
};
ball.prototype.doCommand = function(direction) {
  if (direction === "X") {
    this.size += 2;
  } else if (direction === "Z") {
    this.size -= 2;
  } else if (direction === "C") {
    this.speed -= 2;
  } else if (direction === "V") {
    this.speed += 2;
  }
  if (this.speed < 0) {
    this.speed = 1;
  }
  if (this.size < 0) {
    this.size = 1;
  }
}
var Ball = new ball();
var commands = ["Z", "X", "C", "V"];

var keyActions = {
  32: "stop",
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down",
  90: "Z",
  88: "X",
  67: "C",
  86: "V"
};

$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
  for (var n = 0; n < commands.length; n++) {
    if (direction === commands[n]) {
      Ball.doCommand(direction);
    } else {
      Ball.setDirection(direction);
    }
  };
});
setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  Ball.draw();
  Ball.move();
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}, 30);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please, post the code as plain text within the question body rather than posting a link.

Comment: the code is too huge, and stackoverflow tells me to give more comments or more text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code.

First thing in keydown Handler we don't need for loop. I have changed this.
I have updated Do Command as well. Here is the problem: you are not updating xspeed & yspeed in the doCommand I did that change for c & v.
I hope this is what you are expecting.

Please find the updated code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"><title>Drawing some circles...</title>
</head>
<body>
   <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
   <canvas id = "canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
   <script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var width = canvas.width;
      var height = canvas.height;
      function circle(x,y,radius,fillCircle)
      {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
         if(fillCircle)
         {
            ctx.fill();
         }
         else
         {
            ctx.stroke();
         }
      };
      function ball()
      {
         this.speed = 5;
         this.x = width/2;
         this.y = height/2;
         this.xSpeed = this.speed;
         this.ySpeed = 0;
         this.size = 5;
      };
      ball.prototype.move = function()
      {
         this.x += this.xSpeed;
         this.y += this.ySpeed;

         if (this.x<0)
         {
            this.x = width;
         }
         else if(this.x>width)
         {
            this.x = 0;
         }

         if (this.y>height)
         {
            this.y = 0;
         }
         else if(this.y<0)
         {
            this.y = height;
         }
      };
      ball.prototype.draw = function()
      {
         circle(this.x,this.y,this.size,true);
      };
      ball.prototype.setDirection = function(direction)
      {
         if(direction ==="up")
         {
            this.xSpeed = 0;
            this.ySpeed = -this.speed;
         }else if(direction ==="down")
         {
            this.xSpeed = 0;
            this.ySpeed = this.speed;
         }else if(direction ==="right")
         {
            this.xSpeed = this.speed;
            this.ySpeed = 0;
         }else if(direction ==="left")
         {
            this.xSpeed = -this.speed;
            this.ySpeed = 0;
         }else if(direction ==="stop")
         {
            this.xSpeed = 0;
            this.ySpeed = 0;
         }
      };
      ball.prototype.doCommand = function(direction)
      {
         if(direction ==="X")
         {
            this.size +=2;
         }else if(direction ==="Z"){
            this.size -=2;
         }else if(direction ==="C"){
            this.speed -=2;         
         }else if(direction ==="V"){
            this.speed +=2;
         }       
         if(this.speed<0)
         {
            this.speed = 1;
         }
         if(this.size<0)
         {
            this.size = 1;
         }
         if(direction ==="V" || direction ==="C") {
             if(this.xSpeed!=0) {
                this.xSpeed = this.speed;
            }
            if(this.ySpeed!=0) {
                this.ySpeed = this.speed;
            }
         }           
      }
      var Ball = new ball();
      var commands = ["Z","X","C","V"];

      var keyActions = {
         32:"stop",
         37:"left",
         38:"up",
         39:"right",
         40:"down",
         90:"Z",
         88:"X",
         67:"C",
         86:"V"
      };

      $("body").keydown(function (event)
   {
      var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
      if(commands.includes(direction))
      {
         Ball.doCommand(direction);
      }
      else{
         Ball.setDirection(direction);
      }
   });
   setInterval(function()
   {
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
      Ball.draw();
      Ball.move();
      ctx.strokeRect(0,0,width,height);
   }, 30);

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```